# ggplot two lines in one graph, error code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot, rescale

I am pretty new to RStudio and try to plot two different lines in one graph. X-scale should be the year and the y-scale should be tons Carbon per hectar. Then I want to plot two lines for two different forest management types (BAUca and NATUREca). With the first 4 lines of the code I changed my data from factor to numeric.

```
mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) {
  if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x
})
sapply(mydata, class)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=BAUca, group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(y=NATUREca)
```

I get the following error code:
Error in UseMethod("rescale") :
no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "factor"

As I said I already changed my data to numeric. So I am wondering why it stills give me this kind of error.

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
Year    BAUca   NATUREca
2020    80.31   80.31
2025    83.43   92.76
2030    83.73   102.56
2035    84.76   112.72
2040    84.65   121.83
2045    84.84   131.38
2050    86.18   141.33
```

Would be very happy if someone has a solution for this error.
Greetings,
Frederic

Comment: Please provide an example of your data in order to make it reproducible.

Comment: @Phil I added the data in the question. It is sufficient like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `y` into `aesthetic`:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050),
  BAUca = c(80.31, 83.43, 83.73, 84.76, 84.65, 84.84, 86.18),
  NATUREca = c(80.31, 92.76, 102.56, 112.72, 121.83, 131.38, 141.33)
)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=BAUca, group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(aes(y=NATUREca))
```

[image]